# ansible: failed_when is not working to validate user input

Tags: ansible

i am trying ansible playbook to prompt for a user input and if condition is not satisfied it should fail & exit.

my playbook is as below.

```
[ansible@localhost ~]$ cat dummy.yml
---
- name: testing failed_when
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
      - pause:
           prompt: "\nPlease ente 1:\n"
        register: given
        failed_when: given.user_input != 1
      - set_fact:
           SER: "{{ given.user_input }}"
      - fail:
           msg: "unacceptable"
        when: SER is undefined
```

and when i execute this, it's getting failed even though i give input as 1..

```
[ansible@localhost ~]$ ansible-playbook dummy.yml

PLAY [testing failed_when] *********************************************************************************************************************

TASK [pause] ***********************************************************************************************************************************
[pause]

Please ente 1:
:1
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "delta": 1, "echo": true, "failed_when_result": true, "rc": 0, "start": "2020-05-29 02:52:27.318633", "stderr": "", "stdout": "Paused for 0.02 minutes", "stop": "2020-05-29 02:52:28.556987", "user_input": "1"}

NO MORE HOSTS LEFT *****************************************************************************************************************************

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

[ansible@localhost ~]$
```

and i have tried using "fail" as shown below, it's not working too.

```
  tasks:
      - pause:
           prompt: "\nPlease ente 1:\n"
        register: given
      - set_fact:
           SER: "{{ given.user_input }}"

      - fail:
           msg: "unacceptable"
        when: SER != 1
```

result:

```
[ansible@localhost ~]$ ansible-playbook dummy.yml

PLAY [testing failed_when] *********************************************************************************************************************

TASK [pause] ***********************************************************************************************************************************
[pause]

Please ente 1:
:1
ok: [localhost]

TASK [set_fact] ********************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [fail] ************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "unacceptable"}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost
```

in both of above cases, i have entered "1" as user input & it's still failing.. Not sure what mistake i did.

please help.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition `when` expands by default the variable to string. Either compare `SER` to string

```yaml
    when: SER != "1"
```

or convert `SER` to integer

```yaml
    when: SER|int != 1
```